# Discord bot just repeats the same message over and over

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm new to python and coding in general. I created this bot MIDA and whenever I send a message for the bot to respond to it replies with a different command's output and then sends that message over and over again.

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.server.channels:
        if str(channel) == "conversing":
            await client.send_message(f"""Welcome Consul {member.mention}""")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(enter id here)
    channels = ("bot-requests")
    if str(message.channel) in channels:
        if message.content.find("MIDA hello there"):
            await message.channel.send("GENERAL KENOBI!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(enter id here)
    channels = ("bot-requests")
    if message.content.find("MIDA users"):
        await message.channel.send(f"""# number of members {id.member_count}""")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(enter id here)
    channels = ("bot-requests")
    if message.content.find("MIDA Skyrim sucks"):
        await message.channel.send("The voice of Todd Howard echos in the past: You're on thin ice kiddo.")
```

Answer (score 0):

In on_message you need to check if the message was sent by the bot, otherwise it will keep responding to it's own message.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the three different definitions of the same function. Also, I recommend you use the [built-in commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html), it'll be much easier in the long-term.